# posting a ui ux feedback challenge here

Tags: discussion

Can i post a UI UX feedback challenge like http://challenge.nexus360.mobi/ here?

Comment: See this page for the answer: http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 9):

I don't think so. Something like this would really belong in the chat rooms but you're not able to even access those until you get 20 rep.

In the [tour of this site](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tour) they say that "UX Stack Exchange is a question and answer site ...This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."

You're not really asking a direct question to get help with UX problems. I'd take a look at the tour in the Help section in the top navigation bar to get a better feel for what you can and can't do here.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a spec-work site? That's usually frowned upon in general as it's not good for the industry, the designer, or the client.